# Windows phone 7 ads

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

Hello I don't understand the ads system of wp 7

1. Do I need to code something or dropping the component on the botton of my screen is enough
2. I can't find how much can I get from this... Does the user have to click the add so that I'll get paid.

Thanks
Asaf

Comment: This doesn't work in all countries though. Make sure you check you location first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Microsoft ads, through PubCenter, (pubcenter.microsoft.com) your pay is based on impressions, while nearly all others are based on clicks.

To use the PubCenter ads, the ad SDK is part of the Windows Phone tools install.  You can find information on using this at advertising.microsoft.com/mobile-apps and at create.msdn.com.

As far as how much you will make, it depends on your app, how popular it is, how well targeted your ads are, and more.  eCPM is the rate you're paid, and it is on a bid process, and varies from minute to minute, depending on what ads are available within your targeted categories.

For instance, I have one app that typically makes close to 1000 impressions per day, and brings in about $1.00 to $1.50 per day, depending on impressions and eCPM, of course.  I have another app that brings in nearly the same number of impressions, sometimes more, and yet, it only makes me about 20% of the first one.  I'm still working on tweaking the ad categories to increase my eCPM so that it will make as much as the first one, but I'm thinking it is part art, and part luck.

Comment: Thanks ecpm is the keyword I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can find the answer for your questions here: [Microsoft Advertising](http://advertising.microsoft.com/mobile-apps)

Comment: I have looked for a number e.g: x$ for one and sdk guide options. I found the site you gave me but despite the fact that it may contain all the data I need it does not have a summary of the subjects that interest me and I guess anyone that is going to use this feature. Nonetheless this is a very I,portent reference. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, sadly numbers i couldn't give you because i live in a country where this doesn't work, so couldn't try it. :(